Are there languages from which complete texts survived, but which have not been deciphered yet?
I have the impression that we can nowadays read quite a lot of ancient languages, even those that were long forgotten, like Sumerian.
There are obviously quite a lot of lost languages from which we have no text at all, only some names and single words, or maybe just lists of harvest and taxes.
Are there languages from which complete texts survived, but which have not been deciphered yet?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

Linear A. four more. Others

Wikipedia has a list of undeciphered writing systems. Probably a couple dozen or so. I'm not sure how one would determine if texts are "complete" without being able to read them.

@MCW Thanks, that mainly answers my question.

Questions of this form are a bit of a challenge here, because the answer is either a simple "No" (or I suppose a simple "yes"), or its a list question.

@T.E.D. I thought there might be one or two prominent examples with a large body of text but no deciphering.

Enter the term "Voynich manuscript" into a search engine.

@MichaelHardy I was more interested in languages that were in real use by a larger group of people.

@JFabianMeier : How can we know whether the language of the Voynich manuscript was one of those?

@MichaelHardy The Voynich manuscript is the only surviving manuscript written in that peculiar alphabet. It is likely that this alphabet was not in widespread use, but an invention of a single person or a small group. So even if the underlying language is maybe Hebrew, deciphering the Voynich manuscript is more like solving a riddle that somebody invented than reconstructing a real language together with its canonical alphabet.

@JFabianMeier The Voynich Manuscript is likely a hoax and the "text" is probably gibberish.

There are several,  but the two that should come to mind immediately are:

Linear A, the writing system of Minoan civilization in the early 2nd millennium BCE. It was the inspiration for the Mycenean writing system Linear B. Although Linear B has been deciphered, Linear A has not because it's unknown what language it encodes.

Rongorongo, collections of linearly arranged symbols found on wooden objects found on Rapa Nui (Easter Island), and is presumably a script for the Rapa Nui language.


Honorable mention to Harappan from objects found in Indus Valley Civilization, but most of these inscriptions are only a few symbols, and the language it encodes is unknown.

Indeed, Linear B is simply Greek written in Cretan characters. We don't know what language Linear A is or even to what language family it might belong, so we don't really have anywhere to start in terms of decoding it.
